# How to make a Nuxt 3 plugin globally available without using nuxtApp?

Tags: nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I am migrating a Nuxt 2 Project that uses a lot of plugins like these:

```
// MyPlugin.ts
interface MyPlugin {
    someFunction: () => string;
    someData: string[]
}

export default ({ store }: NuxtAppOptions, inject: Inject) => {

    const someFunction = () => "";
    const someData = [];

    inject('myPlugin', {
        someFunction,
        someData: someData,
    } as MyPlugin);
};

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
    interface Vue {
        $myPlugin: MyPlugin;
    }
}
```

And then it is usable in other components like this:

```
this.$myPlugin.someFunction()
```

and in templates directly like this:

```
<div>{{ $myPlugin.someData }}</div>
```

without having to import it.

Now with Nuxt 3, I read about [providers](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins), but I would still need to use

```
useNuxtApp()
```

in order to access my Plugin.

**Is there a better way, without the verbosity of the initial nuxt 2 solution?**